# If is page, archive or search output this code

Tags: php, pages

Hi there I'm trying to make this code works for more than just home page but I'm getting errors while trying to accomplish it... can someone help me? I'm trying to use this:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) {?>
    <div>Flash Gordon</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But I want to use more just only is_front_page like, if `is_front_page` or`is_archive` or if `is_search` as well. Ho can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `OR` conditions like this.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {?>
    <div>Flash Gordon</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Same time frame, :-). Will remove my answer. +1 for beating me :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad I could help you on this. :)